# Displaying blob images objects from a list to a web page in mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, blob

I am working on a project where I load 12 long blob images from a database and save them in a list.

In the html page, i have to display the images but i am getting errors when trying to convert a blob to an image.

I get the error `Parameter is not valid` when using memory stream. No matter whatever change I make, unable to get rid of that error.

Below is the code:

```
    public Image getProduct_Image(byte[] imagebytes)
    {
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[imagebytes.Length];

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
        ms.Position = 0;

        ms.Read((byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        ms.ToArray();
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        System.Drawing.Image returnImage = Image.FromStream((Stream) ms);
             Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(returnImage);
             return bmp;
    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using an `Image` object? If you're dealing with images on the web, I'd expect a regular `<img>` tag pointed to a handler (ashx or FileContentResult) which retrieves the bytes from the database and dumps them directly to the HTTP output. Would that be possible in your scenario?

Comment: Oh!! Well frankly, i have't tried that! Do you have any article as to how to use that ?

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on my comment:

You can write images from bytes into HTML in a few lines of code with an .ashx handler, but since you're using MVC, it's actually really easy.

First you just set up a controller action - assume your image is identifiable based on an integer ID. It's just a single line to return those bytes as content.

```
public FileContentResult SomeImage(int id)
{
    byte[] bytes = GetImageBytesFromDatabase(id);
    return File(bytes, "image/jpeg");
}
```

Your markup is just an image tag with the source as this controller action:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("SomeImage", "Home", new { id = 123 })" />
```

This actually creates the following, depending on whether you're doing anything special with your routing:

```
<img src="/Home/SomeImage/123" />
or possibly
<img src="/Home/SomeImage?id=123" />
```

Comment: Guys, one of my friends figured it out! Well, its my mistake. The insertion did not happen properly! Thanks for all ur help.

Answer (score 1):

I dont see you actually filling your byteArray with data anywhere!

Also, why do you create the byteArray variable in the first place? you already have the blob  data as a byte[] in the input variable imagebytes. Remove byteArray and use imagebytes.

```
public Image getProduct_Image(byte[] imagebytes)
{
    try
    {
        if(imagebytes == null || imagebytes.Length == 0)
            throw new InvalidDataException("The blob does not contain any data");  

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imagebytes);
        ms.Position = 0;
        ms.Read((imagebytes, 0, imagebytes.Length);
        ms.ToArray();
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        System.Drawing.Image returnImage = Image.FromStream((Stream) ms);
        return new Bitmap(returnImage);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // deal with the exception
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the same but i still get the error as "parameter is not valid" at the ms.

        System.Drawing.Image returnImage = Image.FromStream((Stream) ms);

Comment: hmm. could you offer some sample data?

Comment: is the blob an image converted to a byte[] array or is it merely raw RGB values?